What is the drop rate of Fishy Eyeballs?
Per the RoB wiki Fishy Eyeball is a random drop from butchered fish.
Studying one is part of the Fishing tutorial quest and is also a possible quest objective from the Fisherman credo.
Having been fishing diligently for several days now, I've yet to see one drop. My sense (I haven't played the game in six years or so) is that they used to be reasonably common.
What is the actual drop rate? Since W16 is too new, I'll accept answers for W15 and take the risk that Jorb changed it this cycle.

According to the Fandom,

Fishy Eyeball's are obtained by butchering any fish, there is a 1 in 20 chance you will obtain one of these from fish.


Okay that's about what it felt like. I'm guessing W16 has had that nerf'd.  :(

@WilliamWalkerIII if this answered your question, would you consider upvoting/accepting?

I upvoted immediately. I tend to wait on the acceptance until I've given folks a chance to weigh in with counterevidence, but it looks like you'll have that shortly. I don't favor Fandom as a reference generally, but again... the absence of counter argument is weighing in your favor.
